Why are there square holes in the stem wall on either side of my sliding door? I'd like to seal them to prevent pests inside my house
We just bought this house in January, and while touring we noticed a small square hole on each side of the basement sliding door. I figured I'd come back and seal it up at some point. Well, we just noticed a few ants in the house and I'm wondering if this is a possible entry point. The shape of the holes makes me wonder if they are there intentionally and what reason that could be.
I'm planning to bait the ants with terro and then I'd like to seal up these holes, but I want to make sure there isn't any reason the holes are there in the first place.
More photos


not 100% sure but it pay be a weep hole, but those are usually seen on brick houses. IMO blocking this hole will do nothing for the ants, addressing why they are there is usually more helpful (though they still can appear)

Please revise to add information about location, age, construction type, etc. Give us some context.

Ants will get in anywhere & everywhere. Even if they are using those holes now, they'll just choose a different notch, crack or crevice somewhere else if you fill those.

did there used to be a deck there (is this entry like a sunroom/screen porch/extension)?

That looks like fiber-cement siding. It is probably installed over house wrap and may also be on furring strips. The weep holes allow accumulated or draining moisture to escape. You should not plug them without learning more about that situation.
The corresponding notch in the foundation is intriguing. It, along with the apparent age of the concrete, makes me wonder whether this was originally a brick wall which was refurbished and the notch left by a well-meaning but misguided siding installer. It could be completely useless.
